# For loop logic error?

Tags: c++

```
void GameBoard::print(const GameBoard& computerBoard)
{
Grid[0][0] = '1';
Grid[0][1] = '2';
Grid[1][0] = '3';

int i, j;
int sides = SIZE;

cout << "        Your bombs:                    Your navy:" << endl << endl;

for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    // prints your bombs
    cout << sides << "  ";
    for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
    {
        cout << computerBoard.Grid[i][j] << "  ";
    }
    cout << "    ";

    // prints your ships
    cout << sides << "  ";
    for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
    {
        cout << Grid[i][j] << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    sides--;
}

j = 0;
cout << "\n   ";

for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    j = i + 'A';
    cout << (char)j << "  ";
}
cout << "       ";

for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    j = i + 'A';
    cout << (char)j << "  ";
}
cout << endl << endl;
```

}

I am constructing a game like battleship, and need to change the for loop to read..

```
for(i=8;i>0;i--)
```

why does this produce an error?

Sorry if this doesnt make sense, Grid[0][0] should be on the bottom left, but it is currently at the top left.

Comment: What error is being produced? Also, if you're in the for loop that you want (i=8...) are you calling these locations in `Grid`? If so, array indices 0-8 must exist, so it must be `type Grid[9]` or whatever.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your main code containing that line. That single line looks fine to me unless variable i wasn't declared beforehand.

Comment: BTW try not to use the 'magic number'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess what you want is something like

```
for(i=SIZE-1; i>=0; i--)
```

because this is equivalent to

```
for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
```

both of these go from `0..SIZE-1` while

```
for(i=SIZE; i>0; i--)
```

goes from `1..SIZE` (and so if you access an array of length `SIZE` using `arr[i]`, will produce an error).

Comment: Im making an 8 x 8 grid, grid[0][0] is on the top left. I need it to be on the bottom left position.

Comment: The last loop would work if you accessed index `i - 1`, but that would be ugly.

Comment: @Marlon: Nice catch, edited the answer to make this a bit clearer.

Comment: @bluetickk: If the code you posted is the one where `grid[0][0]`, it should help to replace `for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)` with `for(i=SIZE-1; i>=0; i--)` to reverse the output vertical.